# WPF MVVM Filter Bubbles

Tags: wpf

I'm not sure if bubbles is the proper terminology, but this what I am trying to do...

I have a list of clients. The user can click a filter button and a filter panel slides down. The user chooses the filters they want and clicks a little green checkbox to set the filter. (Or a red circle with line through it, to cancel.) Once they set the filter, the filter panel slides out of the view.

I'd like the user to see a series of small filter "bubbles" at the top the list, showing the filters they have selected. Each bubble would have a little 'x' button they could click to cancel that particular filter. I've seen this on many web sites where you can filter down products lists, for instance.

So my questions are:

Is there a proper terminology for this? I've searched on filter bubbles and 
breadcrumbs, but I'm not getting anything.

Is there an established MVVM friendly coding pattern, or control for this? I have some ideas, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel, if I don't have to.

Thanks for any insight.

J

Comment: I've often seen this concept referred to as "[tokens](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/)".

Answer (score 1):

In Angular Material design there are [Chips](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview) (scroll down to see an example with the 'x' to remove a chip).

And there seems to be an implementaion of the material design in XAML which is also available as a NuGet package:
http://materialdesigninxaml.net/

It does implement chips, but the demo pictures don't show it. A simple search on the github page for 'chips' does show that they are present:
https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=chips&type=

Comment: They list the chips on the main page in the box with the clock looking gizmo. Had no problem finding it. Thanks for the insight.